# can rsync transfer my entire samba directory

Tags: rsync, samba

I am fairly new to rsync, so forgive me if I am doing something totally wrong.  I have a Plex media server that I want to back up to my Samba server.  I will set up a cronjob so that this runs every night.  Plex stores all of my media in /samba.  I have subdirectories of /samba/tvShows, /samba/Movies,... inside these subdirectories, there are some folders, and there are some MP4 files. Is there a way for rsync to transfer the entire /samba directory?
I can run `rsync -n -v -e ssh /samba/*.* root@IP:/samba/` and it transfers my MP4 files, I can run `rsync -n -v -e ssh /samba/*/*`  root@IP:/samba/ and this transfers all of the folders, and `rsync -n -v -e ssh /samba/*/*/*.* root@IP:/samba/`gets the rest of it.  this just seems like a horrible way to do this, and I fear that it may miss something at some point if I have a different type of file in the media server that doesn't match my formats. how can I just rsync the entire Samba directory?

Answer (score -1):

You need either `-r` (recurse), or probably better still, `-a` (archive, which implies recurse).

```
rsync -a -v /samba/ root@IP:/samba/
```

Note that you *do* need the trailing slashes on both paths or it won't do what you expect on the second sync.